# showing that two interpolants are identical

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, interpolation

I am trying to show that two interpolants are identical.

Suppose that $x_k$, $k=1,\dots,2^d$ are points on the vertices of a rectangle $D$ in $d$-dimensions. Assume that $f(x_k)$ is available for all values of $x_k$.

I have 2 interpolants, namely:

$\tilde{f_1}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^d} w_k(x)f(x_k)$

and

$\tilde{f_2}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^d} v_k(x)f(x_k)$.

These 2 interpolants satisfy the following properties:

1) $\tilde{f_1}(x_k) = \tilde{f_2}(x_k) = f(x_k), \forall  \, k.$

2) $w_k(x), v_k(x) \ge 0$ and $\sum_k w_k(x) = \sum_k v_k(x) = 1$, i.e. each interpolant is a convex combination of the known values of $f$.

3) if $f$ is linear, i.e. $f(x) = a^Tx + b$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$ then $f = \tilde f_1 = \tilde f_2$ on the rectangular domain $D$.

In 1-d and 2-d, it is easy to show via geometric arguments that these 2 interpolants are identical. However, it is hard to visualize the problem in higher dimensions.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

It is not straightforward to show that $w_k = v_k$ for all $k$ and so I am wondering if there's just a theorem that I did not know which implies the statement I want to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be true.

Consider $d = 2$, $D$ being unit square and $w_k(\xi, \eta)$ being bilinear interpolation basis
$$\begin{aligned}
w_1(\xi, \eta) &= (1 - \xi)(1 - \eta)\\
w_2(\xi, \eta) &= \xi(1 - \eta)\\
w_3(\xi, \eta) &= \xi\eta\\
w_4(\xi, \eta) &= (1 - \xi)\eta.
\end{aligned}
$$
[image]

To define $v_k$ let's split $D$ into two triangles (to be certain, along $\xi = \eta$).
$$\begin{aligned}
v_1(\xi, \eta) &= \begin{cases}
1 - \xi,&\xi > \eta\\
1 - \eta,&\xi \leq \eta
\end{cases}\\
v_2(\xi, \eta) &= \begin{cases}
\xi-\eta,&\xi > \eta\\
0,&\xi \leq \eta
\end{cases}\\
v_3(\xi, \eta) &= \begin{cases}
\eta,&\xi > \eta\\
\xi,&\xi \leq \eta
\end{cases}\\
v_4(\xi, \eta) &= \begin{cases}
0,&\xi > \eta\\
\eta-\xi,&\xi \leq \eta
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
[image]

Every basis satisfies delta property, that is
$$
v_i(x_k) = w_i(x_k) = \delta_{ik}.
$$
Thus, 1) and 2) are satisfied.

Direct checking for $f(\xi, \eta) = \alpha \xi + \beta \eta + \gamma$ shows that 3) holds also.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, uranix! I guess I have no choice but to show that $w_i = v_i$ then.